# How would I get this to work mysql JDBC apk

Tags: java, mysql, apk

Im not quite sure why it's not working I tried it in IntelliJ it worked out fine using it Android Studio's while developing my app it just straight up not works and gives me following.

```
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://IP(I put an IP(there im not stupid)/BBM
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:605)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:218)
at xyz.tton.BBMuisc.MainActivity.authenticate(MainActivity.java:46)
at xyz.tton.BBMuisc.MainActivity.onLogin(MainActivity.java:78)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:468)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7506)
at com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton.performClick(MaterialButton.java:1211)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7483)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29334)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7872)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936)
```

```
public static boolean authenticate(String username, String password) {
        try {
            System.out.println(username);
            System.out.println(password);
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD)
            String query = "SELECT * FROM user_accounts WHERE username = ? AND password = ?";
            PreparedStatement statement = conn.prepareStatement(query);
            statement.setString(1, username);
            statement.setString(2, password);
            ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery();

            boolean isValid = resultSet.next();

            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            conn.close();

            return isValid;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("Time Out!");
        }

        return false;
    }
```